# Polymer: how to link to a PHP file?

Tags: polymer

I'm building a multi-page app using Polymer. In one of the components (or pages, really), I've got a link to a PHP file:

```
<p><a href="/api/export_project.php?id=[[project.number]]">Export as PDF</a></p>
```

This PHP file generates a PDF file. If I point the browser directly to it, it prompts me to save the PDF file - all good.

But when I click on the link form within Polymer, then it goes to my "page not found" component.

My .htaccess file redirects everything to Polymer's index.html, except files that do exist:

```
# Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to index.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

It actually works, since when I point the browser directly to the PHP file it executes it properly.

So, how do I tell Polymer to not treat this link as an internal router thing?

Thanks a lot for any assistance.

Comment: why not use ajax. You can always call function on `a` and inside function make ajax call to php site which will return pdf file (or base64 code or whatever) which you can then convert. I don't think it's problem of .htaccess since you have `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` you can try adding another line 
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/api/export_project.php`  but i don't think it will help

Comment: Ah well, actually the solution was easy, I just needed to use an absolute URL: 

<p><a href="http://www.test.com/api/export_project.php?id=[[project.number]]">Export as PDF</a></p>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was pretty simple, I just needed to use an absolute URL, rather than relative:

```
<p><a href="http://www.something.com/api/export_project.php?id=[[project.number]]">Export as PDF</a></p>
```